# what does this mean "a periodic chain has nontrivial topology"

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I'm reading an article about nonhermitian sytems it says that "a periodic chain has nontrivial topology". What does this mean?

Here is the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05312.pdf

Comment: A trivial topology on a set Y is usually defined to be the collection $\{ \emptyset, Y\}$ and any other topology on Y is nontrivial.

Comment: Can you expand more?

Comment: So the only open subsets of $Y$ here are the empty set and $Y$ itself. All other subsets of $Y$ are closed. Meaning the trivial topology is the smallest topology on $Y$.

Comment: Can you explain it for the periodic chain? For example how the periodic chain has non trivial topology

Comment: You should first explain **what** a periodic chain is.